# app.UseMvc Route Exception when updating from .NET Core 1 to .NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-1.0

I am upgrading my project from .NET Core 1 to .NET Core 2.

Following the Official Docs - [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/) - I edited my csproj to contain the following packages.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.2" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" Version="11.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="7.5.2" />
```

Then updated the `Program.cs` to.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
}
```

and also changed the Startup Class to this.

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Load Configuration from appsettings.json
        services.Configure<IdentityServerSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerSettings"));
        services.AddOptions();

        var identityServerOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<IdentityServerSettings>>().Value;
        services.AddMvc(o =>
        {
            if (identityServerOptions.EnableSSL)
                o.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddIdentityServerAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.Authority = identityServerOptions.Authority;
                opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = identityServerOptions.EnableSSL;
                opt.ApiName = identityServerOptions.ApiName;
            });
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        #region Identity Server Config
        // Setup Identity Server Options for this API - 
        app.UseAuthentication();

        #endregion

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // tried this 
        app.UseMvc();

        // and this
        //app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute(); 

        // and this
        //app.UseMvc(routes =>
        //{
        //    routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        //});
    }
```

I have tried all three

1 - `app.UseMvc();`

2 - `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();`

3 -

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

But whenever I run the project I get an Exception: 'Sequence contains more than one matching element'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I followed the docs and did the upgrades from `AspNetCore 1` to `ASPNetCore.All` v2.0.7 too (I know v2.0.8 just came out but Azure doesn't support it just yet so I am holding on the upgrade). I had no problem compiling with `FluentValidation` v7.5.2.

Just wanna share how I did it.

#### Create an extension method

```
namespace DL.SO.Web.UI.Extensions
{
    public static class MvcBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static void AddFluentValidationServices(this IMvcBuilder mvcBuilder)
        {
            mvcBuilder.AddFluentValidation(fv =>
            {
                fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CreateProductValidator>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

#### Call it after `AddMvc()`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddFluentValidationServices();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this had nothing to do with .NET Core upgrading. But is an issue with how I've setup Fluent Validation.

During the upgrade I also upgraded `FluentValidation.AspNetCore` from 7.2.1 to 7.5.*. Which was causing the exception.

After downgrading back to 7.2.1 the solution is working fine.

I will Post more on the issue when I find a solution to get it working with `FluentValidation.AspNetCore` V 7.5.